# How can I dynamic sort the value of a nested Map in spring jpa?

Tags: java, sorting, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a table for player, a separated player_ranking table storing ranking of different types. Using JPA, the player_ranking is stored in the property rankings.

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners( ObservedEntityTransactionListener.class )
public class Player extends ObservedEntity
{    
    @Id
    @Column
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    private Map<String, Integer> rankings;
}
```

ranking of a player is something like the below:

```
{"Goal": 15},
{"Assist": 10},
{"Red": 1},
{"Yellow": 3}
```

I need to add dynamic sorting to the Integer part of ranking. How can I do it?

I tried the below with JPA Pageable/Sort but it cannot find it as a property.

```
 Sort.by( Sort.Direction.ASC, Player_.ranking.Assist)
```

I tried the below criteriaBuilder but it cannot find that property also.

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.asc( root.get( "rankings.Assist" ) ) );
```

**Update** With my solution

Turns out a MapJoin is what I need, after joining, I can use the .value() and .key() methods to build further Criteria.

```
       MapJoin<Player, String, Integer> playerRankingMap = root.joinMap( "rankings" );

       var playSortedByRank = query.orderBy( criteriaBuilder.asc( playerRankingMap.value() ) );
       var playSortedByAssist = criteriaBuilder.equal( u2.key(), "Assist" );
       return playSortedByAssist;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.asc(root.joinMap("rankings").value()));
```